# How to configure DBPROP_COMMANDTIMEOUT?

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to configure the property of DBPROP_COMMANDTIMEOUT ?

Can this property be configured in Database ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as what we have received and tested the results on DBPROP_COMMANDTIMEOUT is that the default timeout of 30 seconds does not seem to work at database level, also when specified to any other value. Like for few specified a default of 30 seconds ran more than 50+ and thus neglecting the time out.

So we believe SQL seems nothing to play a role in setting that time-out value, instead that would be the application to decide the value or provide for same.

For what i have read more on this :

> The timeout no longer counts, once the client library have received
> some    data back from SQL Server.
>
> If the timeout elapses when SQL Server has been inserting data into
> a    table for 30 seconds, or even worse been updating rows row 30
> seconds,    it will not yield on the spot. The effect of the currently
> executing     statement must be rolled back. And roll-backs usually
> takes longer than    command that started the operation.
>
> Note that an entire user-defined transaction is not rollback, even if
> it was started in the query batch that timed out. This you must cater
> for yourself. But the current statement is always rolled back

Also, would suggest you to read [There's no such thing as a query timeout...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/khen1234/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-query-timeout)

On how to configure as per you're second question, you can follow this thread [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40754/how-can-i-set-timeout-by-view-user-or-role)

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I would use a timer for each command and manually stop the command that is overtime. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Connection timeout is always set by client. The timeout is normally configured when the connection is created. In order to prevent recompilation of client code the timeout interval is often stored in a config file, registry entry etc

You cannot configure the timeout on the database itself.

Comment: Thank you very much! And is there any example to configure DBPROP_COMMANDTIMEOUT in client ?